# Replacing a HDD in a RAID 5 after the Hot Spare already rebuilt

Tags: raid5, adaptec

(I'll try to be brief on the background) I have 2 RAID 5 arrays using an Adaptec 5405 controller. In the past when a drive failed I was able to swap the drive with a new one and it would rebuild automatically.

A few months ago a drive failed and I replaced it. It did not automatically rebuild itself. I ended up forcing the array back online and I set the drive as a hot spare drive.

Today, the second array had a drive failure. The system automatically picked up the hot spare and rebuilt itself. I swapped out the failed drive with a new one and in ICP storage manager, the drive just shows up as "ready" and is not part of the array when I click on the logical devices.

Should I just set the new drive as a hot spare? (I would also note that the old hot spare drive that was automatically picked up is still labeled as a hot spare although it is now included as part of the array when I click on the logical device.)

Comment: Just relabel the former hot spare and add the new drive as new hot spare.

Comment: I managed to find some documentation on this: "Remove the ‘hot spare’ designation from a disk drive that is no longer being used as a hot spare. (When a hot spare is built into a logical drive after a disk drive failure, it retains its ‘hot spare’ designation even though it can no longer protect the logical drives it’s assigned to."

Comment: My hesitation with this is the icon for the hot-spare should have a yellow plus sign (Hot spare has been built into a logical drive after disk drive failure)

Currently its a blue plus sign which indicate a healthy hot spare.

Comment: I'm undergoing a data migration currently but can try to remove the hot-spare status afterwards. Thanks